# Problemas con ruta donde guardo archivo de sitio web

Tags: php, html

hace unos días no puedo subir archivos a sitio creado en PHP. Será el // que sale en el error?. Adjunto el código y mensaje de error.

[image: Imagen con el error de ruta]

```
if(@copy(@$_FILES[$this->campoformulario]['tmp_name'],$this->carpeta."/".$nombre)){
```

Comment: Normalmente eso no es lío. Igual, mejor si lo quitas. Revisa los permisos del usuario que corre el proceso de apache, sobre la carpeta y subcarpetas de public_html. PD. Todavía se juega Hattrick? :P

Comment: Cambié los permisos pero no me funcionó

Comment: Y ese directorio existe? Así completo como sale? Si le das cd /var/...., llegas al directorio?